# How can I write image to MySQL database?

Tags: databaselink, databases

I have a database, such as:
[image: Database schema]

In *Mathematica*, the final code is:

```
img1=Export["/home/user/Desktop/1.jpg",resultimg1];
```

I tried `SQLInsert[conn,"mathematica",{"image"},{img1}];`

but the MySQL result is:

[image: Example with just image name inserted]

> How can I write the **image** to MySQL database?

Comment: Try SQLBinary as described in http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DataTypeMapping.html

Comment: @user5990: `Export` returns the full path to the file it wrote and that's what you are inserting into your database. If, as I guess, you want to write the file content instead of the filename you could e.g. use `ExportString` and `ToCharacterCode` to get a binary representation of the file content to insert into your database...

Comment: Yes, there is an example in the docs that does this exactly http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLBinary.html

Comment: @Ajasja how's that different than what I pointed to above?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Not at all, I just did not scroll far enough to see it. no more late night mma.se for me:)

Comment: Good reference for Database Link, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export` returns the filename to which your data was exported. Your code does insert that filename into your database, and you see that this actually does work. What you most probably want is to insert the file content, not the filename, into the database. For that you need a combination of `ExportString`, `ToCharacterCode` and `SQLBinary`. This is described, as Ajasja has mentioned, in the [documentation for `SQLBinary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLBinary.html). Here is how it would look like for your example:

```
filecontent = ToCharacterCode[ExportString[resultimg1,"JPEG"]];
SQLInsert[conn,"mathematica",{"image"},{SQLBinary[filecontent]}];
```

Depending on how you are going to read the data you might need to take care of the correct encoding, if you read and write both from the same machine with Mathematica I believe the defaults should work alright.

Comment: Thanks for your good solution :)